# Can't signin to an AD (SAML) provider via aws-amplify sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-amplify

Cross posted from: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4901

We created a user pool and App in Cognito and connected it to our AD via SAML. The config works, as we can login via the hosted UI. I can then see the user record if I go to Users and Groups in Cognito.

If I then try to login via Amplify SDK (Code below) I get NotAuthorizedException. As a test I added a users via Users and Groups, and updated the Client app to point also to "Cognito User Pool". Logged in via the hosted UI to set the password and then used the same Code snippet to login and everything worked fine, using the same exact params for the auth config. So, I only get the NotAuthorizedException for a user that is marked as EXTERNAL_PROVIDER in Cognito.

Packages:

```
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^2.1.3",
"@aws-amplify/core": "^2.2.2"
```

Code:
(Some numbers Xed out)

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
const Amplify = require('@aws-amplify/core')
const Auth = require('@aws-amplify/auth');

Amplify.default.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        userPoolId: 'us-east-1_s6bRXXXX',
        userPoolWebClientId: '71dpfannjbht1qfhjvXXXXXX',
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'  //Added this based on SO post but it didnt help
    }
});

async function signin() {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.default.signIn("chananb+dev@gmail.com", "My_password");
    console.log('user :', user); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error :', error);
  }
}

signin();
```